# I am writing my first shiny app. I have two errors: '&' not meaninful for factors and 'occupation' not found in the app

Tags: r, shinyapps

This is a simple shiny app.   Three inputs using the income.csv dataset in R.

I am attaching the code.  I can't find where I am making the mistake.  I am not getting an output presumably because of the two error messages.

One message appears in the console as 
Warning in Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘&’ not meaningful for factors
Warning: Error in %in%: object 'occupation' not found

occupation is a field in the dataset.

The other message appears when I run the App;  object 'occupation' not found

I'd really appreciate your input.

This is the code:

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

setwd("C:/Users/Corsair_Barillas/Documents/FAB/Quant/Professional Certifications/UC Berkeley/Module 10 Interactive User Interface")
income <- read.csv("income.csv")
Occupationlist <- unique(income$occupation)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Module 10 Assignment"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "subset_income", label = "Select Income Bracket:", 
                  choices = unique(income$income), multiple = FALSE),
      selectInput(inputId = "set_yaxis", label = "Select Criteria:", 
                  choices = c(HoursPerWeek = "hours_per_week", CapitalLoss = "capital_loss")),
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "subset_occupation", label = "Select Occupation:", 
                  choices = Occupationlist, selected = Occupationlist)),
    mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "myfigure"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  create_subset <- reactive(income %>%
                              filter(capital_loss > 0) &
                              income %in% input$subset_income &
                              occupation %in% input$subset_occupation) 

  output$myfigure <- renderPlot(ggplot(create_subset()) +
                                  geom_boxplot(aes_string(x = occupation, y = set_yaxis,
                                                        col = "blue"))+
                                  theme_bw(18) + 
                                  ylab("Capital Loss") +
                                  xlab("Occupation"))
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: You’ve got a misplaced bracket in the `filter` command. You probably want to close the `filter` expression after the third condition. Another point: Do you really have a column named `income` in the `data.frame` named `income`?

Comment: thank you!  I'll verify the filter expression.  And yes, there is a column named income inside income.  the dataset is one we are using in class to learn R